# SharePoint configure service instance failed with error the server must be local server

Tags: sharepoint

In sharepoint 2016, run Farm Configuration Wizard in CA, some services failed to configure with the error message: **The server must be the local server.**

Here is the detail information:

> The following errors were encountered while provisioning services:
>
> The service instance "Request Management Service Instance" could not
>   be provisioned because of the following error: The server must be the
>   local server. Parameter name: server
>
> The service instance "" could not be provisioned because of the
>   following error: The server must be the local server. Parameter name:
>   server
>
> The service instance "Launcher Service" could not be provisioned
>   because of the following error: The server must be the local server.
>   Parameter name: server
>
> The service instance "Load Balancer Service" could not be provisioned
>   because of the following error: The server must be the local server.
>   Parameter name: server
>
> Correlation ID: 13ecac9d-a542-c064-6e61-d3b8550380ae

And I check the SharePoint log, found following error messages:

> 10/13/2016 13:34:47.42    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x10F4)
>     0x08C4  SharePoint Foundation           Topology
>     a39jv   Unexpected  The server 'server' is not the local
>   server.   5febac9d-d5e6-c064-6e61-db8c09504994 10/13/2016 13:34:47.42
>     OWSTIMER.EXE (0x10F4)                       0x08C4  SharePoint Foundation
>     General                         a55tp   Exception   Configuring service
>   instance failed: SPRequestManagementServiceInstance
>   System.ArgumentException: The server must be the local server. 
>   Parameter name: server     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerRoleManager..ctor(SPServer
>   server)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerRoleManager.get_LocalOrThrow()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdminConfigServicesJob.Execute(Guid
>   targetInstanceId) StackTrace:  at onetnative.dll:
>   (sig=02ac9fdd-a9da-4cc6-9939-165ab7ad2add|2|onetnative.pdb,
>   offset=36D3D) at onetnative.dll:
>   (offset=1E30E)    5febac9d-d5e6-c064-6e61-db8c09504994 10/13/2016
>   13:34:47.42   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x10F4)
>     0x08C4  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service
>     c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation 4, ULSException14, 269cd32d "sharepoint foundation",
>   100010ff "16.0.4351.0", 1f65804a "microsoft.sharepoint", 10001150
>   "16.0.4432.0", 57ca6fa6 "sat sep  3 14:37:26 2016", 00003ce6
>   "00003ce6", 0000006e "0000006e", 44395864 "argumentexception",
>   007df4cf "a55tp"  5febac9d-d5e6-c064-6e61-db8c09504994 10/13/2016
>   13:34:47.42   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x10F4)

I tried serveral methods, and still can't fix it. So can you help me?

Comment: I have fixed it. Because the logged in farm administrator is not in SQL server configuration database and content database **SharePoint_Shell_Access** role, you can refer to this post to configure it: [https://lightningtools.com/sharepoint_2010/sharepoint-farm-administrator-sharepoint-farm-administrator/](https://lightningtools.com/sharepoint_2010/sharepoint-farm-administrator-sharepoint-farm-administrator/)

Comment: Run **Farm Configuration Wizard** successfully, but the there is still many "the server must be local" error in logs.